# Cut text into two string using string delimiter - bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, cut

I want to cut string into two string using an string

```
 CH  7 ][ Elapsed: 0 s ][ 2021-11-27 12:55

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH   MB   ENC CIPHER  AUTH ESSID

 EE:EE:EE:EE:EE:EE  -82        3        0    0   6  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Tenda
 FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  -90        4        0    0   1  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Wifi

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Notes  Probes

 EE:EE:EE:EE:EE:EE  AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA  -63    0 - 1e     0        3
 EE:EE:EE:EE:EE:EE  BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB  -74    0 - 1      0        1
```

I want to cut my text using this delimiter  `BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Notes  Probes` I try with `awk -F 'BSSID' '{print $1}' file` but it cut all occurrence, I want to cut only last occurrence.
desired output :

```
 CH  7 ][ Elapsed: 0 s ][ 2021-11-27 12:55

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH   MB   ENC CIPHER  AUTH ESSID

 EE:EE:EE:EE:EE:EE  -82        3        0    0   6  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Tenda
 FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF  -90        4        0    0   1  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Wifi
```

Comment: Please shorten your overlong lines.

Comment: I try with `awk -F 'BSSID' '{print $1}' file` but it cut all occurrence, I want to cut only last occurrence.

Comment: What do you mean by _`cut` into two strings_? with `awk` `sed` `grep` etc... you'll only get **one** processed string as output

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Notes  Probes/{exit} 1' file
```